# How to dynamically create obj property in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a JSON like this:

```
{
   '2014-1-1':
             {
             'objA':
                   {
                        'attrA': 'A'
                        'attrB': 'B'
                   }
             }

}
```

I tried:

```
  obj['2014-1-1'] = {'objA' : { 'attrA' : 'A'}};

  obj['2014-1-1'] = {'objA' : { 'attrB' : 'B'}};
```

But I only see B value on my object now, I guess 'because 'objA' is being overridden, how do I add 'attrA' and 'attrB' both for objA ?

Answer (score 1):

Once the property exists, simply access it and set a value, don't overwrite:

```
obj['2014-1-1'] = {'objA' : { 'attrA' : 'A'}};
obj['2014-1-1']['objA']['attrB'] = 'B';
```

You'd probably just want to make a check to see if the property exists, if not, create it, then assign:

```
if (!obj['2014-1-1'].hasOwnProperty('objA')) {
    obj['2014-1-1']['objA'] = {}
}

obj['2014-1-1']['objA']['attrA'] = 'A';
obj['2014-1-1']['objA']['attrB'] = 'B';
```

Comment: what if I don't know if 'objA' exist?

Comment: Use the `hasOwnProperty` method to check for existence: `if (obj['2014-1-1'].hasOwnProperty('objA'))`

Comment: @user1701840 You make a check?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you are overwriting the object. You can do it like this:

```
obj['2014-1-1'] = {'objA' : { 'attrA' : 'A', 'attrB' : 'B'}};
```

`attrA` and `attrB` are two different properties of `objA` so this way you set both of them.